# How can pass data from AuthorizationHandler to Controller in Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I used a specific authorization policy for user log in, so created custom Authorization Handler. And I would like to display use a specific alert message if they failed the policy. I read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies#accessing-mvc-request-context-in-handlers) and found that I could access AuthorizationFilterContext via casting AuthorizationHandlerContext. I tried to add message to HttpContext.Items property and access it in my controller, but it returns false when i check it with TryGetValue method.

```
if (context.HasFailed && context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext mvcContext)
{
 mvcContext.HttpContext.Items["message"] = "alert message";
}
```

and this is the code i used in controller action that will be executed when authorization has failed,

```
public IActionResult Login()
        {
            bool t = HttpContext.Items.TryGetValue("message", out Object e);
            //t is false
            TempData["message"] = e as string;
            return View();
        }
```

and this is startup class where i registered all authentication services.

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddCookie(options =>
                    {
                        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/Login";
                        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                    });
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CustomRequirement", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new CustomRequirement()));
            });
```

Is there any way i could work it out?

---

added full handler.

```
public class CustomRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<CustomRequirement>
    {

        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, CustomRequirement requirement)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> claims = context.User.Claims.ToDictionary(p => p.Type, p => p.Value);
            if (claims.TryGetValue("SessionId", out string sessionId) && claims.TryGetValue("UserId", out string userName) )
            {
                bool qq = ;//we check session id and user id that is stored in our database, true if valid.
                if (qq)
                {
                    context.Succeed(requirement);
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Fail();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                context.Fail();
            }

            if (context.HasFailed && context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext mvcContext)


   {
            var tempData = _tempDictionaryFactory.GetTempData(mvcContext.HttpContext);
            tempData["message"] = "alert message";
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I guess add this will make dependency injected?

```
private ITempDataDictionaryFactory _tempDictionaryFactory;

        public SingleConcurrentSessionHandler(ITempDataDictionaryFactory tempDataDictionaryFactory)
        {
            _tempDictionaryFactory = tempDataDictionaryFactory;
        }
```

---

**Update** - here is the logger log for new empty project with custom AuthorizationHandler.

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:50236/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed for user: (null).
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
      Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was challenged.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action WebApplication1.HomeController.Index (WebApplication1) in 6217.0905ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 6389.8033ms 302
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:50236/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method WebApplication1.Controllers.AccountController.Login (WebApplication1) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json.Internal.JsonResultExecutor[1]
      Executing JsonResult, writing value .
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action WebApplication1.Controllers.AccountController.Login (WebApplication1) in 3723.1458ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 3741.0345ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:50236/favicon.ico
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 4.1151ms 404 text/plain
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use TempData to show your message

There are you need `ITempDataDictionaryFactory` and `IHttpContextAccessor` or for context you can get from `mvcContext.HttpContext`

```
if (context.HasFailed && context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext mvcContext)
{
    var tempData = _tempDataDictionaryFactory.GetTempData(mvcContext.HttpContext);
    tempData["message"] = "alert message";
}
```

then you can get it in Login method via TempData

```
public IActionResult Login()
{
    string message = null;
    var item = TempData.FirstOrDefault(x =>x.Key == key);

    if (item.Value != null)
    {
        message = (string)item.Value;
    }

     return View();
}
```

Why your code not working:

`HttpContext` creating per request it means that you inserting `mvcContext.HttpContext.Items["message"] = "alert message";` will be able only for current request, when you use Authorization in controller or his method it will insert you message to current request and redirect to your AccessDeniedPath or LoginPath and new `HttpContext` will be created for this request without your message. To share some info between requests you can use TempData or other methods.

**Update** Try to get httpContext from accessor Here full code

add to startup `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`

```
public class CustomRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<CustomRequirement>
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;
        private readonly ITempDataDictionaryFactory _tempDataDictionaryFactory;

        public CustomRequirementHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext, ITempDataDictionaryFactory tempDataDictionary)
        {
            _httpContext = httpContext;
            _tempDataDictionaryFactory = tempDataDictionary;
        }

        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, CustomRequirement requirement)
        {
            ///////
            //Your logic
            ///////

            if (context.HasFailed)
            {
                var tempData = _tempDataDictionaryFactory.GetTempData(_httpContext.HttpContext);
                tempData["message"] = "alert message";
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE** When context.Fail(); performed tempData dont injecting via tempdata provider but you can call tempdata provider for executing manual save

Here example:

```
public class CustomRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<CustomRequirement>
{
    private readonly ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;

    public CustomRequirementHandler(ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider)
    {
        _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, CustomRequirement requirement)
    {
        ///////
        //Your logic
        ///////
        context.Fail();


        if (context.HasFailed && context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext mvcContext)
        {
            _tempDataProvider.SaveTempData(mvcContext.HttpContext, new Dictionary<string, object>() {  { "message","alertmessage "+DateTime.Now } });
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, which TempDataProvider should i use to generate TempDataDictionaryFactory?

Comment: you dont need to create it, you should use DI to get it. Can you share your Authorization Handler?

Comment: @itkhomi just did, i guess adding constructor like that will work this out.

Comment: @ringord, sure, now try to get it worked. Just change TempDataDictionaryFactory to your injected _tempDictionaryFactory

Comment: well, i just tried it and TempData has no element when i access in controller(Account/Login).

Comment: @ringord, can you confirm that only one redirect performed? and your CustomRequirementHandler not hitted twice?

Comment: I added this ``[Authorize(Policy = "CustomRequirement")] to my Account Controller. And i just checked it with debugger, and it is just hitted once, right after `CompletedTask` returned i moved to Account Controller Constructor and then move to `login` action.

Comment: @ringord, try to use my update, and check context.HasFailed equal true to get insert

Comment: I tried yours, TempData still has no element in the account controller.

Comment: @ringord, did you check that  'var tempData = _tempDataDictionaryFactory.GetTempData(_httpContext.HttpContext);
                tempData["message"] = "alert message";' executed?

Comment: It seems like when it fails and gets redirected to `AccessDeniedPath `, 'account/login' page in my case, it populate a new http context. I make new empty project and tested the code, when it failed(whenever `context.succeed(requirement)` method not invoked, asp.net core redirect the request to the new path, and perhaps in this case the browser fail to save tempdata cookie?

Comment: @ringord, something goes wrong when context.Fail(); performed but manualy cookie insert works well with it. When context.Succeed(requirement); tempData working well

Comment: So you mean instead of let asp framework inserting cookie, i should insert cookie after invoking `context.Fail()` method?

Comment: @ringord, Oh i got it!! manualy TempDate save wroks pretty well, wait for update

Comment: It works!! Thanks. Is this issue because of extra redirection in framework level? or just a bug?

Comment: You right, CustomRequirementHandler redirects before tempdata saves changes(its not get base request pipeline). It maybe bug or secure feature

Comment: As far as i know is that if `context.hasfailed` equals to false, then the framework redirect to `accessdenied path`, but in case `context.hasfailed` equals to true, the framework process the request to end point(instead of redirection), because the handler works as authorize filter. So this might be the issue?

Comment: Sure, i think it is

Answer (score 1):

In asp.net core for an API controller, note that I'm using `_httpContext.Items`, e.g.:

`_httpContext.Items["Token"] = token` and in there you can store whatever object you want.

In the controller simply do this:

`return HttpContext.Items["Token"]` as CustomToken;

```
public class HasConstituentIdHandler : AuthorizationHandler<HasConstituentIdRequirement>
{
    private readonly OpenIddictTokenManager<CustomToken> _tokenManager;
    private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;

    public HasConstituentIdHandler(OpenIddictTokenManager<CustomToken> tokenManager, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _tokenManager = tokenManager;
        _httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
     
    }
    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, HasConstituentIdRequirement requirement)
    {
        var tokenId = context.User.GetTokenId();

        if (tokenId != null)
        {
            

            var token = await _tokenManager.FindByIdAsync(tokenId);
            token.Context = new EventContext {ConstituentId = "junk"};//todo: s.f for now
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token?.Context?.ConstituentId))
            {
                if (_httpContext != null) _httpContext.Items["Token"] = token;
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
        }
        if (_httpContext != null)
        {
            
               var response = _httpContext.Response;
            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Missing constituent information! Please log in again.");
            response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            response.ContentType = "application/json";
            await response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My answer relates to asp.net core

Comment: I use this option to my asp.net core web project, when i make an ajax request. Thanks.